# Javascript Loop (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm currently in the beginning stages of learning Javascript and was wondering how you'd be able to loop through this array and output all the data as html content:

```
var links = new Array(); //Missing this part as code

links[0] = new Array();
links[0]["linkName"] = "W3Schools";
links[0]["linkLogo"] = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png";
links[0]["linkURL"] = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
links[0]["linkDescription"] = "W3Schools is a web developer information website, with tutorials and references relating to web development topics such as HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP.";

links[1] = new Array();
links[1]["linkName"] = "Code Academy";
links[1]["linkLogo"] = "";
links[1]["linkURL"] = "https://www.codecademy.com/";
links[1]["linkDescription"] = "Codecademy is an online interactive platform that offers free coding classes in 9 different programming languages.";

links[2] = new Array();
links[2]["linkName"] = "";
links[2]["linkLogo"] = "http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg";
links[2]["linkURL"] = "http://www.w3.org/";
links[2]["linkDescription"] = "The World Wide Web Consortium is the main international standards organization for the World Wide Web.";
```

Comment: "output all the data as html content" is really vague.  Also, try googling and showing what you've tried before asking a SO question.  Folks will be happy to help you along.

Comment: That's a rather weird data structure, wouldn't it be easier to have each array item contain an object with properties? (I'm not sure `links[0]["linkName"] = "W3Schools";` will do what you think it will)

Comment: The people downvoting you are pedantic idiots upset about your failure to define 'html' and 'output'. Accept my apologies on behalf of them. Most people on SO are awesome, so is the community as a whole! Give .forEach a google, loops in JS, and maybe general JS tutorials! You may have diven into the deep end so take it slow and keep on coding :) All the best!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words Stan! :) I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your structure, we can do this:

```js
var links = new Array(); // Missing this part as code

links[0] = new Array();
links[0]["linkName"] = "W3Schools";
links[0]["linkLogo"] = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png";
links[0]["linkURL"] = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
links[0]["linkDescription"] = "W3Schools is a web developer information website, with tutorials and references relating to web development topics such as HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP.";

links[1] = new Array();
links[1]["linkName"] = "Code Academy";
links[1]["linkLogo"] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-5_nn_mBDGb0/U3RBFBDiozI/AAAAAAAAm60/kOmwt-F5x8g/s1600/codeacademy.png";
links[1]["linkURL"] = "https://www.codecademy.com/";
links[1]["linkDescription"] = "Codecademy is an online interactive platform that offers free coding classes in 9 different programming languages.";

links[2] = new Array();
links[2]["linkName"] = "The World Wide Web Consortium";
links[2]["linkLogo"] = "http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg";
links[2]["linkURL"] = "http://www.w3.org/";
links[2]["linkDescription"] = "The World Wide Web Consortium is the main international standards organization for the World Wide Web.";

// Loop through the main array
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i){

  // As we loop, we'll create new HTML elements that will be configured
  // with the information we extract from the objects in the array:
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  
  // Use data in the nested array to configure the new HTML element
  a.href = links[i]["linkURL"];
  img.src = links[i]["linkLogo"];
  img.alt = links[i]["linkDescription"];
  img.title = links[i]["linkName"];
  
  // Place the image inside of the link:
  a.appendChild(img);
  
  // Place the link inside of the div
  div.appendChild(a);
  
  // Inject div element into the web page
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
img {width:200px}
```

However, in JavaScript, arrays are best for storing single data items or even nested arrays. **But, when you need to store names and values to go with those names, it's best to use an Object, which is designed for key/value pair storage.**

Here is your data, reorganized into objects that are then placed into an array and finally, the array is looped, the object data is extracted and the data is placed into HTML elements.

```js
// First set up objects to store the name/value pairs (arrays don't do this)
var object1 = {
 linkName : "W3Schools",
 linkLogo : "http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png",
 linkURL : "http://www.w3schools.com/",
 linkDescription : "W3Schools is a web developer information website, with tutorials and references relating to web development topics such as HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP."
};

var object2 = {
 linkName : "Code Academy",
 linkLogo : "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-5_nn_mBDGb0/U3RBFBDiozI/AAAAAAAAm60/kOmwt-F5x8g/s1600/codeacademy.png",
 linkURL : "https://www.codecademy.com/",
 linkDescription : "Codecademy is an online interactive platform that offers free coding classes in 9 different programming languages."
};

var object3 = {
 linkName : "The World Wide Web Consortium",
 linkLogo : "http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg",
 linkURL : "http://www.w3.org/",
 linkDescription : "The World Wide Web Consortium is the main international standards organization for the World Wide Web."
};

// Place the objects into an array:
var objects = [object1, object2, object3];

// Loop through each of the objects in the array
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i){

  // As we loop, we'll create new HTML elements that will be configured
  // with the information we extract from the objects in the array:
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  
  // Use data in the object to configure the new HTML element
  a.href = objects[i].linkURL;
  img.src = objects[i].linkLogo;
  img.alt = objects[i].linkDescription;
  img.title = objects[i].linkName;
  
  // Place the image inside of the link:
  a.appendChild(img);
  
  // Place the link inside of the div
  div.appendChild(a);
  
  // Inject div element into the web page
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
img {width: 200px;}
```

Comment: I feel haunted :)

Comment: @Lain Why is that?

Comment: Seeing the same names multiple times a day is kinda unusual, at least for me :)

Comment: @Lain Ah, LOL! I didn't even notice. I'm on SO pretty much every day.

Answer (score 1):

The following code maps the given structure into an array of strings representing html that incorporates all of the given elements:

```
const linksAsHTML = links.map(link=>
`<a href="${link["linkURL"]}" title="${links["linkDescription"]}">
  <img src="${link["linkLogo"]}" alt="${links["linkName"] }"/>
</a>`);
```

There are a number of ways to transform this array of strings into html on a page, though as a beginner I suggest learning how to use [jQuery](https://jquery.org/)

Note: this is just one of an infinite number of ways to do this, but hopefully this helps you figure out exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I would suggest beginners stay very far away from JQuery as it invariably turns out that they misuse and overuse it without ever learning the basics of JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I believe I understand your concern -- I could have written up something up about using "document.createElement" and cross-browser idiosyncrasies, etc., but, ahem, "ain't nobody got time for that". jQuery does makes some things a lot easier by hiding unnecessary complexity, which can be a double-edged sword, but you shouldn't assume that someone is going to misuse it. Further, for some people, learning jQuery without knowing the rest of JS is fine for their purposes so there's no reason to force them to learn all parts of the language if they don't have to.

Comment: As someone who has been teaching JavaScript (and a whole host of other programming languages) for 25+ years, I can say with certainty that using JQuery without learning JavaScript well, it ALWAYS a recipe for disaster. Especially since the DOM now has APIs for many of the things that attracted developers to JQuery in the first place. I cannot tell you how often I see the JQuery library included in code that does little more than simple event binding or queries.

Comment: @ScottMarcus point taken. How would you improve my answer?

Comment: Your answer is fine as long as the target audience will have ES6 compliant browsers. I was just commenting on your JQuery comment, not your answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus. Thanks! I like your answer too! :)

Comment: Right back at you. +1

Answer (score 0):

The data sturucture is kind of inconclusive, so I assume those are meant to be anchors:

```
links = []; //A man missed a declaration

links[0] = new Array();
links[0]["linkName"] = "W3Schools";
links[0]["linkLogo"] = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png";
links[0]["linkURL"] = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
links[0]["linkDescription"] = "W3Schools is a web developer information website, with tutorials and references relating to web development topics such as HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP.";

links[1] = new Array();
links[1]["linkName"] = "Code Academy";
links[1]["linkLogo"] = "";
links[1]["linkURL"] = "https://www.codecademy.com/";
links[1]["linkDescription"] = "Codecademy is an online interactive platform that offers free coding classes in 9 different programming languages.";

links[2] = new Array();
links[2]["linkName"] = "";
links[2]["linkLogo"] = "http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg";
links[2]["linkURL"] = "http://www.w3.org/";
links[2]["linkDescription"] = "The World Wide Web Consortium is the main international standards organization for the World Wide Web.";

//Looping though the array
for(var i=0, j=links.length; i<j; i++){
    if (!!links[i]['linkName']){ //Displaying empty links makes less sense
        //Creating a new anchor
        var tA = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
        tA.href = links[i]['linkURL']; //Assigning the href
        tA.innerHTML = links[i]['linkName']; //Assigning the name
        tA.title = links[i]['linkDescription'];  //Assigning the description

    //Adding logo if available
    if(!!links[i]['linkLogo']){
        var tI = tA.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
        tI.src = links[i]['linkLogo']
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to output all of that data and format it into HTML, your code doesn't do that, any other ideas?

Comment: @JuliaM: I do not comprehend that comment, I am afraid.

Answer (score -1):

```
 for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
   someFn(arr[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.